# iCloud and existing Core Data store for "shoe box" app

Tags: core-data, icloud

I have an existing app with a single Core Data store. It is similar to what Apple calls a shoe box app.
There are many records already stored. I was able to add the necessary code easily to get iCloud integration setup.

I build the new app on my iPod touch and on my iPad, both running iOS5.

The iPod has the existing data. However the data doesn't show up on the iPad.
The app has iTunes file sharing enabled, so through iTunes I drop the sqlite db on both devices.

Now I try making changes and see if iCloud will now keep them in synch. It does not.

How do you get your existing data on both devices and then have iCloud keep them in synch from that point forward.

---

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *cloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:@"ABCD1234.com.yourcompany.appID"];

NSDictionary *options = nil;

if (nil != cloudURL) {

    NSString *coreDataCloudContent = [[cloudURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data"];
    cloudURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:coreDataCloudContent];

    options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, 
               @"myApp.store", NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey,
               cloudURL, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey,
               nil];
}
else {

    options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, 
               nil];
}
```

And I have this added to the managedObjectContext for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
```

---

There are several thousand people using my app and have entered lots of data. They do not want to enter it all again. I want to deliver this new version of the app that is iCloud enabled but until I can get the data to show up on both and stay in synch there is no point.

Comment: " I was able to add the necessary code easily to get iCloud integration setup" - maybe it wasn't as easy as you think ;). You're going to need to include some of your iCloud code and some description of how your data store is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good nights sleep always helps.

Note, I have a backup of my SQLite DB already taken from my main device through iTunes file sharing.

I have iTunes files sharing enabled.I build the app on each device and run in XCode. Stop each device. Go to iTunes. Through file sharing I delete the sqlite database on each device. Sync the devices. Then I choose one device and restore my backed up database onto it using iTunes file sharing. Sync the device.

Launch my app on the device with the restored db. Then I launch my app on the second device that has no db (remember, deleted it above). Waited for a moment, and then behold, the data did appear. I think I heard the faint sound of an angelic choir singing.